# Configure Webpack to build a directory of LESS files into corresponding CSS files

Tags: plugins, less, webpack, watch

I'm hoping to use Webpack compile all our less files in `/less` to `/public/css` and include them in our server-side templates as regular css (**not** sticking the text into the  using ExtractText plugin or overloading require).

That is, I'm trying to get Webpack + a LESS loader or plugin to glob to compile all the .less files:

/less/foo.less
/less/bar.less
/less/unknown-new-less-file.less
...

and output them to

/public/css/foo.less
/public/css/bar.less
/less/unkown-new-less-file.less

I then want to include them in our app by pulling in css file using
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="foo.css">`

I tried using a Bash script and `lessc` instead of Webpack, which worked fine, but won't enable us to automatically re-compile the LESS when the source files change.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was using Webpack as a task runner, which it is not.

I was resisting adding Gulp or Make. Gulp because it turns into a giant unmaintainable mess and Make even though it's great because it's a little hard for teams to learn.

I ended up using something like fswatch in an npm script to re-run lessc.

The Less docs recommend using grunt, Gulp, or dev-mode in-browser parsing: http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser-watch-mode.

Comment: See this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44859700/4319253. Tell me if I need to add more info.

Comment: @S.Klechkovski having a single LESS file that imports all the others is an interesting solution, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of webpack, you can use [`chokidar`](https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/chokidar-cli) with `lessc`. 
First, install chokidar: `npm install chokidar-cli`

Then, use it to watch your less files: 
`chokidar "less/*.less" -c "lessc less/foo.less public/css/foo.css"`

[Chokidar documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/chokidar-cli)

More information about why not to use webpack for compiling less separately: [Can I use webpack to generate CSS and JS separately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35322958/can-i-use-webpack-to-generate-css-and-js-separately)