# import CSS and JS files using Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-style-loader, html-webpack-plugin

I have a directory structure like this:

[image]

and inside node_modules:

```
 >node_modules
  >./bin
   >webpack.config.js
  >bootstrap
   >bootstrap.css
   >bootstrap.js
```

I need to generate separate CSS and JS bundles like this:

**custom-styles.css, custom-js.js, style-libs.css, js-libs.js**

where `style-libs` and `js-libs` should contain syles and js files of all libraries like bootstrap and jQuery. Here's what I have done so far:

**webpack.config.js:**

```
const path = require('path');
const basedir = path.join(__dirname, '../../client');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const stylesPath = path.join(__dirname, '../bootstrap/dist/css');

var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  watch: true,

  // Script to bundle using webpack
  entry: path.join(basedir, 'src', 'Client.js'),
  // Output directory and bundled file
  output: {
    path: path.join(basedir, 'dist'),
    filename: 'app.js'
  },
  // Configure module loaders (for JS ES6, JSX, etc.)
  module: {
    // Babel loader for JS(X) files, presets configured in .babelrc
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            loader: 'babel',
            babelrc: false,
            query: {
                presets: ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"],
                cacheDirectory: true // TODO: only on development
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader")
        },
    ]
  },
  // Set plugins (for index.html, optimizations, etc.)
  plugins: [
     // Generate index.html
     new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: path.join(basedir, 'src', 'index.html'),
        filename: 'index.html'
     }),
     new ExtractTextPlugin(stylesPath + "/bootstrap.css", {
        allChunks: true,
     })
  ]
};
```

**Client.js**

```
import * as p from 'babel-polyfill';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

I am able to run the app and render all of the components correctly except loading the external JS and CSS file using `webpack`.

I'm not much experienced with webpack and find it really difficult it wrap my hear around it. There're are a few simple questions:

1- *Is this configuration correct? If yes, then how can I include my CSS and JS files in components using ES6. Something like `import` keyword.*

2- *Should I even be using webpack for CSS files?*

3- *How to specify individual directories for input and their respective output files in webpack? Something like `all-custom.js` should be output for `custom1.js` and `custom2.js`?*

I know these are some very basic question and I tried Google but didn't find a single tutorial for Webpack that is simple and targets beginners.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35322958/can-i-use-webpack-to-generate-css-and-js-separately This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35322958/can-i-use-webpack-to-generate-css-and-js-separately/59237067#59237067 seems to be the way to go now with `MiniCssExtractPlugin`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After playing out with Webpack in multiple projects, I figured out how Webpack loads stuff. Since the question is still unanswered, I decided to do it myself for anybody with same need.

**Directory structure**

```
->assets
  ->css
    ->my-style-1.css //custom styling file 1
    ->my-style-2.css //custom styling file 2

->src
  ->app
    ->app.js
    ->variables.js

  ->libs.js //require all js libraries here
  ->styles-custom.js //require all custom css files here
  ->styles-libs.js //require all style libraries here

->node_modules
->index.html
->package.json
->webpack.config.js
```

**Bundle 1 (main code of app)**

`app.js`: assuming this is main file and app starts from here

```
var msgs = require('./variables');
//similarly import other js files you need in this bundle

//your application code here...
document.getElementById('heading').innerText = msgs.foo;
document.getElementById('sub-heading').innerText = msgs.bar;
```

**Bundle 2 (js modules)**

`libs.js`: this file will require all modules needed

```
require('bootstrap');
//similarly import other js libraries you need in this bundle
```

**Bundle 3 (external css files)**

`styles-libs.js`: this file will require all external css files

```
require('bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
//similarly import other css libraries you need in this bundle
```

**Bundle 4 (custom css files)**

`styles-custom.js`: this file will require all custom css files

```
require('../assets/css/my-style-1.css');
require('../assets/css/my-style-2.css');
//similarly import other css files you need in this bundle
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const extractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'app': './src/app/app.js', //specifying bundle with custom js files
        'libs': './src/libs.js', //specifying bundle with js libraries
        'styles-custom': './src/styles-custom.js', //specifying bundle with custom css files
        'styles-libs': './src/styles-libs.js', //specifying bundle with css libraries
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            //used for loading css files
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: extractTextPlugin.extract({ fallbackLoader: 'style-loader', loader: 'css-loader?sourceMap' })
            },
            //used for loading fonts and images
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), //directory for output files
        filename: '[name].js' //using [name] will create a bundle with same file name as source
    },
    plugins: [
        new extractTextPlugin('[name].css'), //is used for generating css file bundles

        //use this for adding jquery
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jQuery'
        })
    ]
}
```

**index.html**

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/styles-libs.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/styles-custom.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <h2 id="heading"></h2>
  <h3>
    <label id="sub-heading" class="label label-info"></label>
  </h3>
  <script src="dist/libs.js"></script>
  <script src="dist/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 10):

1. You can include css & JS files using import in es6 in the source files in your project. example:

> import './style.css';
>
> import Style from './path/style.js';

NB. Generally You need to code in es5 in **webpack.config.js** file. If you want to use es6 just follow the link [How can I use ES6 in webpack.config.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31903692/how-to-use-es6-in-webpack-config)

2. You can use https://github.com/webpack/css-loader for CSS configuration.
3. You can use code splitting in webpack and specify multiple entry point but that will generate multiple output files. Have a look at multiple entry point section of that following link. 
   https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html

Comment: I did same but webpack isn't generating any files for `styles`. can u look in to my code and figure out where something is wrong?

Comment: you can import the css directly in the client.js after configuring the webpack.config.js . and the recommended way to configure webpack.config.js can be found here https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1789

Comment: can you share your full code or a test project so that i can check.