# 2 different css bundles based on folder location (compiled from less \w webpack)

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, bundling-and-minification

We are developing a webapplication with a custom cms dashboard in react.

Our basic folder structure looks like this:

```
src
  -client
    -app
      -less
       ...
    -cms
      -less
       ...
   -server
-webpack-config
    -development
       -client.js
       -server.js
    -production
```

What we are trying to achieve sounds simple: but we are struggling getting it to work.

The less-files in app/less && cms/less should each be bundled to a seperate css file.

This way we can load the correct css file based on what main component gets loaded in react (app / cms dashboard ). The styling for our cms is totally different from our app.

Our current webpack config for the client:

```
var path  = require('path');
var webpack  = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var HTMLCompressionPlugin = require('html-compression-webpack-        plugin');

module.exports = {
    cache: true,
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../src/client/index.js'),
    devtool: 'eval',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../build/public'),
        pathinfo: true,
        filename: 'client.js',
        publicPath: "/"
    }, 
    module: {
        rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/, 
            exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../node_modules'),
            use: [{
                loader: 'babel-loader?cacheDirectory=true',
                options: {
                    "babelrc": false,
                    "presets": [
                    ["es2015",{"modules": false}],
                    "react",
                    "stage-0"
                    ],
                    "plugins": [
                    "transform-react-constant-elements",
                    "transform-react-inline-elements",
                    "transform-react-remove-prop-types"
                    ],
                    "compact": false
                }
            }]
        },
        {
            test: /\.less$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                notExtractLoader: "style-loader",
                loader: "css-loader?sourceMap?minimize!less-loader?   sourceMap",
                publicPath: "/"
            })
        },
        {
            test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g)$/i,
            use: 'url-loader?limit=50000'
        }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        compress: {
            warnings: false,
            screw_ie8: false,
            conditionals: false,
            unused: false,
            comparisons: false,
            sequences: false,
            dead_code: false,
            evaluate: false,
            if_return: false,
            join_vars: false
        },
        output: {
            comments: true
        },
        sourceMap: true
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
            'NODE_ENV': '"development"'
        }
    }),new HtmlWebpackPlugin({       
        template: path.resolve(__dirname,       '../../src/client/app/public/index.html'),
        inject: 'body',
        filename: 'index.html',
        hash: false,
        cache: true,
        minify: {},
        alwaysWriteToDisk: true
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin("[contenthash].css"),
    new HTMLCompressionPlugin({
        deleteOriginals: false,
        assetsRelativeOutputDirectory: '../../build/public',
        minRatio: 1
    })
    ]
}
```

Any tips and help would be very welcome: thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To generate multiple bundles for your css files, you can create a `js` file that `requires` your css files and then add it inside `entry` property of `wepack` config. After that you can use **[ExtractTextWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/extract-text-webpack-plugin/)**
 to generate single `css` files. See this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39015521/import-css-and-js-files-using-webpack/43276340) for code.