How can I bundle my full-stack TS application with HTML all into one html,js and css file?
At first I had a simple TS app, used tsc to compile the typescript into js. But eventually the application got bigger and now I need to bundle everything into one HTML, CSS and JS file. I tried webpack but it brought a whole lot of problems with itself.
Here is my webpack.config.js file.
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './src',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: ['html-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
                include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')],
            },
            {
                test: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: [
                            '@babel/preset-env',
                            '@babel/preset-typescript',
                        ],
                    },
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx'],
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/public/pages/report/index.html',
            favicon: './src/public/media/favicon-review.ico',
        }),
    ],
};

Also, a screenshot of my folder structure
Folder Structure
I get errors like this while trying to compile with webpack:

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/static/pages/report/styles/index.css' in 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\review\src\public\pages\report' at C:\Users\User\Desktop\review\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:2094:28
at C:\Users\User\Desktop\review\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:895:13


It's unknown how pages/report/styles/index.css is used in the project

What do you mean by that?

Where does "styles/index.css" string occur in project code? It's unknown how it's loaded and so it's impossible to say how this can be fixed.

It is in the src/public/pages/report/styles folder, I set static folder via express.static() function. When I deploy server locally, tsc and node sees it, however, whenever I try to bundle the project via webpack, somehow my /static folder become unknown to webpack through HTML files.

I mean not file itself but where it's used. Please, clarify this. Is it loaded as 


They are used like this in my HTML files. Sorry for my poor question structure.
It's not intended to be used like that, and webpack isn't supposed to do anything in static/public folder, it's kept as is. Usually resources to be processed are kept in src/assets/ and are explicitly imported in app modules like import 'src/assets/index.css'. This results in .css being bundled inside .js and creating inline 
Another option is to output .css alongside with .js in "output" location,  you need to replace  style-loader with mini-css-extract https://stackoverflow.com/q/35322958 . The resulting css is the one you can load with 
